# Show $=\bigg( \int |\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot 1_{[0,n]}|^p \bigg)^{1/p} <\infty$

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that:
$=\bigg( \int |\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot 1_{[0,n]}|^p \bigg)^{1/p} <\infty$

I can show this by:
$$\sum (\frac{n}{n^{2}})^p=\sum \frac{1}{n^p} <\infty$$ for all p>1

However, it requires me to first take the integral and then apply the ^p:
$$\bigg( \int |\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot 1_{[0,n]}|^p \bigg)^{1/p} <\infty$$
$$\bigg( (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2})^p \bigg)^{1/p} <\infty$$

In other words, I can't explain if I am first taking the integral and then applying the ^p on the inner function in the sum or reverse. Furthermore the sum of square is not equal to the square of sums, so I am mising some argument to do this

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are you integrating? With respect to what measure and what variable? I can see no free variable to integrate over.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Presumably it's w.r.t Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is equivalent to showing that
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \mathbb{1}_{[0,n]} (x)\right)^p \mathrm dx < +\infty$$
We split the integral using
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \mathrm dx= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^k\mathrm dx$$
Now, for $k-1 \le x <k$ we have
$$\mathbb{1}_{[0,n]} (x)=
\begin{cases} 1 & \mathrm{ if \ \ } k \le n \\ 0 & \mathrm{ if \ \ } k >n
\end{cases}
$$
Thus everything simplifies to 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^k \left( \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \mathbb{1}_{[0,n]} (x)\right)^p \mathrm dx= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{k-1}^k \left( \sum_{n=k}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^p \mathrm dx= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{n=k}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^p $$

To show that this series is convergent, we use the integral test.
$$\left( \sum_{n=k}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^p \sim \left( \int_k^{\infty}  \frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2}\right)^p = \frac{1}{k^p}$$

Thus we have convergence for $p>1$.

Comment: Thanks, this was the missing piece. There is a theorem in my textbook that says when you interchange sum and integral. That solved the task